# Are spectral approaches to Graph Neural Networks still considered?

Tags: geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks, spectral-analysis

I've been reading several papers and reviews about Graph Neural Networks, and I still feel a bit confused about the difference between the two approaches, and also if the spatial approaches have somehow 'overcome' spectral ones. I will add some of my understanding:

*Graph Neural Networks* take inspiration from the convolution operation between two signals in a Euclidean domain, as a way to *combine* the features on the nodes as it happens for Convolutional Neural Networks. To do this, a notion of convolution has been required for the graph domain. Given $\bf{x},\bf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ two signals, then

$$\bf{x} \, \, *_G \, \, \bf{y} := U(U^Tx \, \odot \, U^Tx)$$

namely, we perform convolution on the graph domain and then take everything back using the inverse Fourier Transform. If we choose a filter $\bf g_\theta = diag(\theta_1, \dots, \theta_N)$ parametrized by some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^N$ then the convolution becomes

$$\bf{x} \, *_G \bf{g_\theta} = Ug_\theta U^T$$

The approach above presents several limitations in terms of non-localization of filters (which depend on the entire graph) and scalability issues if presence of perturbations. So the authors of **ChebNet** proposed the following approximation:

$$\bf{x} \, *_G \bf{g_\theta} = \sum_{i=0}^K \theta_iT_i(\tilde{L})x$$

where $\tilde{L} = 2L/\lambda_{max}-I_n$, $L$ is the *Laplacian* and $T_i$ are Chebyshev polynomials.

Now the crucial step is that Kipf et Al. (2017) have *bridged* the gap between spectral and spatial approaches by proposing a first order approximation of the above equation (assuming $\lambda_{max} =2$ and $\theta = \theta_0 = -\theta_1$):

$$\bf{x} \, *_G \bf{g_\theta} = \theta(I_n+ D^{-1/2}AD^{-1/2})$$

Now, from what I've read so far, it seems that from now on several improvements have been made on the *spatial* approach which defines convolutions on top of node's graph neighbourhood.

The question is, does it still make sense to focus on spectral approaches?